# R data.table: how to use R variables that contain column names?

Tags: r, variables, data.table, interactive

I've read the [data.table documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) several times but I still can't wrap my head around how to do some operations; more generally I still haven't understood the underlying "philosophy" on how to work with variable names. Consider this example problem:

I have a data table with variables 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd':

```
> dt <- data.table(a=c(1,1,2), b=1:3, c=11:13, d=21:23)
> dt
   a b  c  d
1: 1 1 11 21
2: 1 2 12 22
3: 2 3 13 23
```

Suppose my script interactively asks the user to input a column name and corresponding value that should be used to select rows. These two variables are stored in `rowselectname` and `rowselectvalue`:

```
> rowselectname
[1] "a"
> rowselectvalue
[1] 1
```

The script also interactively asks the user to select some row names of interest; their names are stored in `colselectnames`:

```
> colselectnames
[1] "b" "d"
```

Now I want to create a new data table from `dt`, with the rows for which `rowselectname` has the value `rowselectvalue`, and with the columns given by `colselectnames`. The only way I finally managed to do this is as follows:

```
> newdt <- dt[get(rowselectname)==rowselectvalue, ..colselectnames]
> newdt
   b  d
1: 1 21
2: 2 22
```

What I don't understand is why I have to use `get()` for the first selection and `..` for the second. Why not `get()` for both (it doesn't work)? Or why not `..` for both (doesn't work either)? This seems inconsistent to me, but maybe there's another way of doing this with a more consistent syntax. I think the most obvious should simply be `newdt <- dt[rowselectname==rowselectvalue, colselectnames]`, which is how the rest of R seems to work.

I'd really appreciate someone explaining to me how to look at this to make sense of the syntax.

Comment: Some work being done in this area https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues?q=label%3Aprogramming+

Answer (score 2):

We can specify the `colselectnames` in `.SDcols` and select the `.SD` - as we are providing the column name as a string, `get` is used to return the value of the column.  It can also be done by converting to symbol and evaluate (`eval(as.name(rowselectname))`)

```
dt[get(rowselectname)==rowselectvalue, .SD, .SDcols =  colselectnames]
   b  d
1: 1 21
2: 2 22
```

If we want to use `..` operator, use that in the `j`

```
dt[dt[, ..rowselectname][[1]] == rowselectvalue, ..colselectnames]
   b  d
1: 1 21
2: 2 22
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but the syntax here is not obvious either. Still wonder why I have to use `get()` for the first selection and a very complex syntax with `.SD` for the second selection.

Comment: @pglpm If it is a single column, you can also use `[[` to extract the column value.  The `..` is a special operator.`dt[dt[[rowselectname]]==rowselectvalue, .SD, .SDcols =  colselectnames]`

Comment: Thank you, yes I know that (just like with data frames). Unfortunately in this case multiple columns have to be chosen.

Comment: @pglpm Some operators wouldn't work in the `i`.  Here, if you do this in `j` i.e. `dt[dt[, ..rowselectname][[1]] == rowselectvalue, ..colselectnames]
   b  d
1: 1 21
2: 2 22`

Comment: This I didn't know, thank you for the example.

Answer (score 2):

From `data.table` [version 1.14.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) on, `get` has been retired, and you're now able to use the new `env` parameter:

> A new interface for programming on data.table has been added, closing #2655 and many other linked issues. It is built using base R's substitute-like interface via a new env argument to [.data.table. For details see the new vignette [programming on data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html), and the new ?substitute2 manual page.

```r
# install dev version
install.packages("https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/archive/master.tar.gz",  repo = NULL, type = "source")

library(data.table)

dt[rowselectname==rowselectvalue, ..colselectnames, env=list(rowselectname=rowselectname)]

   b  d
1: 1 21
2: 2 22
```

Comment: That's great! it makes data-table syntax much closer to standard R syntax, very useful.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to update the answer, given that `data.table` is already version 1.14.6 and the `env` parameter is still not added.

Answer (score 0):

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) allows for *fast subsetting using the `on` argument and seconday indices* (see the vignette [Secondary indices and auto indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html), in particular chapter 2).

Using the `on` argument we can write

```
library(data.table)
dt[.(rowselectvalue), on = rowselectname, ..colselectnames]
```

> ```
>        b     d
>    <int> <int>
> 1:     1    21
> 2:     2    22
> ```

This concise code is similar to a data.table *join* where the second data.table is created on-the-fly.

---

In case `rowselectvalue` is not found in column  `rowselectname`, the result can be controlled by the `nomatch` argument.

By default, `NA` columns are returned, e.g.,

```
dt[.(rowselectvalue + 10), on = rowselectname, ..colselectnames]
```

> ```
>        b     d
>    <int> <int>
> 1:    NA    NA
> ```

The argument `nomatch = NULL` ensures that an empty data.table is returned, e.g.,

```
dt[.(rowselectvalue + 10), on = rowselectname, ..colselectnames, nomatch = NULL]
```

> ```
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): b,d
> ```

Comment: Thank you for this info. My confusion still remains, the syntax is still counterintuitive and irregular. It looks like we need to use `.()` for one thing and `..` for the other; not much difference with `get()` and `..`.